# Change behavior of the "ADD Media" buttom

Tags: media

I'm trying to modify a certain plugin to make it a little more user-friendly this plugin allows you to embed pdf, the problem is that you have to manually add the short-code each time.

So I just wanted to do a minor behavioral change to the "add  media" button that if it recognizes the media as pdf it will automatically wrap that media-file url with the shotcode

Or how to add a button that can wrap a selected piece of text with that shortcode (if this is simpler to do)

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back trying to add a button which changed a large block of text into a read more accordion. [https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-functionality-to-the-wordpress-visual-editor/](https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-custom-functionality-to-the-wordpress-visual-editor/) Have a look at this tutorial, contains all the information you need on modifying the TinyMCE with your own custom shortcode functions.

Comment: @James Thank you that somewhat helped the made some minor changes to the php and js file, the changes of the php got through nicely but the changes i made to the js are just not getting through >_>

Comment: how are you adding your JS?

Comment: well i just used his plug-in with some minor changes (ie i removed the prompts) and changed the final input text so for the rest the code i have now is 90% similar to what he gave, i'm pretty sure the function add_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) is what adds his JS file to the plugin but any change that i made to it are not getting through for now  i've even simplified that js button to just show an alert message but even that it won't do

Comment: cant help without seeing code snippets...

Comment: @james it nearly exactly as the  tutorial you sent :)

Comment: "nearly...." - Well I cant help then bud, generally on SO we give examples of current code.

Comment: @james the call to the JS file stayed exactly the same, the only thing i really changed is the button functionality, the original code works but even this simple change of the JS file that should just show an alert is not coming through (sorry if i am not "clear")

Answer (score 0):

Js file

```
(function() {
        tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'custom_class', function( editor, url ) {
            // Add Button to Visual Editor Toolbar
            editor.addButton('custom_class', {
                title: 'Insert PDF Tag',
                cmd: 'custom_class',
                image: url + '/icon.png',
            });

            // Add Command when Button Clicked
            editor.addCommand('custom_class', function() {

                var text = editor.selection.getNode();                      
                if ( text.length === 0 ) {
                    alert( 'Please select some text.' );
                    return;
                }
                // Insert selected text back into editor, wrapping it in an anchor tag
                editor.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, '[jupdf-viewer file="' + text + '"]');
            });

            // Enable/disable the button on the node change event
            editor.onNodeChange.add(function( editor ) {
                // Get selected text, and assume we'll disable our button
                var selection = editor.selection.getContent();
                var disable = true;

                // If we have some text selected, don't disable the button
                if ( selection ) {
                    disable = false;
                }
                // Define whether our button should be enabled or disabled
                editor.controlManager.setDisabled( 'custom_class', disable );
            });
        });
    })();
```

Php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: TinyMCE Custom Class
 * Plugin URI: http://sitepoint.com
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Tim Carr
 * Author URI: http://www.n7studios.co.uk
 * Description: TinyMCE Plugin to wrap selected text in a custom CSS class, within the Visual Editor
 * License: GPL2
 */

class TinyMCE_Custom_Class {

    /**
    * Constructor. Called when the plugin is initialised.
    */
    function __construct() {

        if ( is_admin() ) {
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'setup_tinymce_plugin' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'admin_scripts_css' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( &$this, 'admin_footer_scripts' ) );
        }

    }

    /**
    * Check if the current user can edit Posts or Pages, and is using the Visual Editor
    * If so, add some filters so we can register our plugin
    */
    function setup_tinymce_plugin() {

        // Check if the logged in WordPress User can edit Posts or Pages
        // If not, don't register our TinyMCE plugin
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if the logged in WordPress User has the Visual Editor enabled
        // If not, don't register our TinyMCE plugin
        if ( get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) !== 'true' ) {
            return;
        }

        // Setup some filters
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array( &$this, 'add_tinymce_plugin' ) );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', array( &$this, 'add_tinymce_toolbar_button' ) );

    }

    /**
     * Adds a TinyMCE plugin compatible JS file to the TinyMCE / Visual Editor instance
     *
     * @param array $plugin_array Array of registered TinyMCE Plugins
     * @return array Modified array of registered TinyMCE Plugins
     */
    function add_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {

        $plugin_array['custom_class'] = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'tinymce-custom-class.js';
        return $plugin_array;

    }

    /**
     * Adds a button to the TinyMCE / Visual Editor which the user can click
     * to insert a custom CSS class.
     *
     * @param array $buttons Array of registered TinyMCE Buttons
     * @return array Modified array of registered TinyMCE Buttons
     */
    function add_tinymce_toolbar_button( $buttons ) {

        array_push( $buttons, 'custom_class' );
        return $buttons;

    }

    /**
    * Enqueues CSS for TinyMCE Dashicons
    */
    function admin_scripts_css() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'tinymce-custom-class', plugins_url( 'tinymce-custom-class.css', __FILE__ ) );

    }

    /**
    * Adds the Custom Class button to the Quicktags (Text) toolbar of the content editor
    */
    function admin_footer_scripts() {

    // Check the Quicktags script is in use
    if ( ! wp_script_is( 'quicktags' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        QTags.addButton( 'custom_class', 'Wrap text with PDF tag', insert_custom_class );
        function insert_custom_class() {
            // Ask the user to enter a CSS class
            var text = "";
            if(window.getSelection)
                text = window.getSelection().toString();
            if(text === ""){
                alert ("please select some text");
                return;
            }           
            text = text.replace('<a href="','');
            text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('">'));
            // Insert
            QTags.insertContent('[jupdf-viewer file="' + text + '"]');
        }
    </script>
    <?php

    }

}

$tinymce_custom_class = new TinyMCE_Custom_Class;
?>
```

Comment: @james i Added my code :)

Comment: Seems i had to do a CTRL+F5 to update the JS in my browser cache